# 2 stroke path can't see outside stroke illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, creative-cloud

I'm trying to figure out how to get the loop in the B to have an overlapping stroke. As you can see because the inside stroke is so thick you can't see the black outside stroke. I could make the loop a bit bigger bit it would distort the form of the letter.

[image]

Comment: You can copy a section of the stroke where it overlaps then paste it in place and move it to the front. Anything you do is going to make it pretty busy. I think it is fine as is- you don't have the stroke at the bigger bottom loop where it overlaps.

Comment: It's not possible to have stacked strokes weave in and out of each other.  You'll have to create additional objects if you want the black to show around that loop.

Comment: Yes I have come to this realisation that strokes can't imitate a layering effect they have to be two different disconnected paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw some black lines to give the illusion that the strokes are looping over/under each other.

For example

[image]